# Reshaping a tensor with one dimension having different dimension size

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have a tensor `x` of dimension `[num_elem, 128]` and another tensor `batch` of dimension `[num_elem, 1]`. The entries in `batch` are integers from 0 to 511, indicating which batch each entry in `x` corresponds to. In addition, each batch may have different number of counts (e.g `0` appears 22 times, but `29` appears only 5 times).

I want to reshape `x` into a tensor of dimension `[batch_size (512), unk, 128]`, where `unk` refers to the maximum count of an integer in `batch`. Currently I am finding out the frequency of the mode of `batch`, then construct a tensor `x_reshaped` of dimensions `[512, mode_freq, 128]`. Thereafter, I use a for loop to iterate through `x`, assign it to the correct batch (by referring to `batch`) and second dimension of `x_reshaped`. However, this is very slow.

Is there any other more efficient ways to do this? Thank you.

Comment: can you give an example? The tensor `batch` is a bit confusing. Also, did you mean each batch `item` may have a different number of counts?

Comment: @WasiAhmad sure. Let's say ```batch_size``` is 4, so ```batch = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]``` where each entry is an integer from 0 to 3 inclusive. And let's say ```x``` has dimension ```[7, 2]``` instead, where 7 is the number of entries in ```batch``` and 2 is the dimension of each data point. So my ```x_reshaped``` will be ```[4, 3, 2]```, where 4 is the ```batch_size```, 3 comes from the frequency of the mode in ```batch```, and 2 is the dimension of each data point. I apologise for the lack of clarity of my question.